# My app just show one of the values of my database in swift

Tags: swift, database, firebase

When I read data from my database (that includes 9 or 10 child) it just shows me the last value and the other labels are null.

I appreciate your help.

```
let Readuserdata = Database.database().reference().child("Users").child("Customers").child(userid)

    Readuserdata.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    let post = snapshot.value as! [String:Any]
        self.lblgiftprofile.text = post["discountcode"] as? String
        self.lblprofileusername.text = post["name"] as? String
        self.lblemailprofile.text = post["email"] as? String    
    })
```

This shows the last label, that is "email". All the other values are null and if I put `lblemailprofile` at first line it will be null and `lblprofileusername` will appear.

Comment: try to change parameter of : .value to other type like .childAdded

Comment: You have .observeSingleEvent, it only throws the last value, change it .observe

Comment: I actually tried  observe and it is still like that. and the other thing is I don't want to add child I want to read the data and my data are set